# How to implement an ON/OFF switch in a simple digital circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, switching

I'm trying to find a way to implement a simple ON/OFF switch, alongside a START/STOP switch in a simple digital circuit. Here's an example simulation of what I did:

[image]

As you can see, I have some undefined states in the fourth case, when the circuit is off, but its functionality is started. What would be ideal in this case is, when the on/off switch is on (not pushed), the start/stop switch can change states independently, but when the on/off switch is off (pressed down), the start/stop switch goes down with it. What would be a good way to implement this in the digital domain?

---

The circuit is a simple digital dice. When it is started, the LEDs change states between numbers 1-6 quickly, and when it is stopped, the LEDs stop at one of the states. The on/off switch, however, turns off the LEDs and IC that drives them.

Edit: This is the IC that is controlled by ON/OFF switch:
[image]

Comment: In your circuit, it will not make **ANY** difference if you throw out one of the switches and R8 (and replace R8 with a wire). You would get **the same** functionality. You basically have made an "over complex" circuit which uses 2 switches to act as one.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie With one switch left, what happens is the LEDs either flash or they are stopped at one state, but at least one of the LEDs is on all the time.

Comment: Your circuit shows no LEDs so no LEDs are on. You talk about parts of the circuit that aren't in the schematic you show. Then the part that you show makes no sense, it's a pull-up resistor and a switch to control 2 digital inputs. Even though you use 2 resistors and 2 switches, only one of each is needed to perform the 1 / 0 function. Explain **why** you need 2 switches and 2 resistors, so do not explain what they do, explain **how that works** (because: it does not, there is no difference if you press either switch, but feel free to prove me wrong).

Comment: I sense that there is a difference between how you **think** the circuit should work and how it actually works. You're describing how you **think** it should work instead  of understanding what it actually does.

Comment: On/off isn't a logic function at all -- it's just a simple SPST switch in series with your power supply.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I edited the question about what the ON/OFF switch was intended for. However, I think Dave and Elliot answered my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "turn off" the LEDs and ICs, just put a SPST toggle switch in the incoming power line. One position is OFF, the other position is ON. Based on the information you have provided, that is exactly the functionality you want.